# C++ dll loading failed with incorrect format exception when VS is not installed

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, dllimport, dllexport

I have an unmanaged C++ code which compiled to a C++ dll and is called from a C# application.
In the C++ code I user /clr to compile the dll, and I have a wrapper to all functions, so the C# app works fine with the dll.
When trying to run the C# application on a computer without Visual Studio installed I get the following error:

```
"an attemp was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B
```

And then the application crashes.
I've tried to change the Runtime Library to multi-threaded (/MT) but it didn't help.
.NET framework with the needed version is installed on the computer. And the .NET version of the C# application is 4.5, as the version of the dll.
Any suggestion what can help to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you install the necessary runtimes on the target machine?

Comment: Yes. It didn't help.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit application or 64 bit application?  This error usually occurs due to 32-bit/64-bit issues.

Comment: Sounds like you installed them wrongly then

Comment: I compiled the code to 64 bit. But tried also 32, it didn't help.

Comment: I know you said that you have tried 32 and 64 bit, but just as a tip: When dealing with native DLLs, never EVER use the "Any CPU" platform and do specific 32 and 64 builds of your C# assembly. Otherwise you may run into a world of hurt even if you are fixing the problem you are having now when you don't do dynamic loading of different native DLL versions.